# Building an Object System Around shared_ptr

Tags: c++, inheritance, language-design, shared-ptr

I am using `shared_ptr` as my garbage collection for a toy language that I am working on which compiles to C++. My objects derive from a common base class above that there are strings and numbers then there are vectors and maps.  Everything on the c++ side is passed wrapped in `shared_ptr`s so my containers actually hold `shared_ptr` so that when they get destroyed their content is destroyed too.  This scheme works but it feels a bit weird in that containers that are base objects are holding `shared_ptr`s.  Is there a flaw with my design?  If yes what would be an alternative hierarchy around this approach?

Comment: *Above* the common base class are strings and numbers? Please show some code, or a little diagram.

Comment: I don't think I'd use `shared_ptr` for something this complex.  I'd consider making `Object` a reference-counted base class and using something similar to Boost's `intrusive_ptr` or OpenSceneGraph's `ref_ptr`.

Comment: So your toy language falls over the moment you create a cyclical reference?

Comment: Only if creating a cyclical reference is possible in the toy language...

Comment: @jalf: language semantics does not allow cyclic references, you don't need to be a smart ass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd set this up:

```
namespace toylang {

class Object;
// main handle type; use this for all object references
// replace with boost::intrusive_ptr or similar if too inefficient
typedef std::shared_ptr<Object> obj;

class Object
{
    // whatever
};

class Number : public Object
{
    int x;
    // etc
};

class Array : public Object
{
    std::vector<obj> a;
    // etc
}
```

Note that ToyLang arrays in this scheme are vectors of pointers, giving the language reference semantics. This is in fact quite common in dynamic languages: Lisp, Python, and others work like that. As long as you don't have circular references, `shared_ptr`'s reference counting will give you proper garbage collection.

Comment: The inability to GC circular references is pretty significant, IMO.  Generally you can deal with this using `weak_ptr`, but dealing with it in the general case for arbitrary inputs is not going to be easy.

Comment: @Tim: for a toy language, it may not be very significant and there are domain-specific languages that can do without. Python still uses reference counting with a separate GC to clean up what garbage reference counting leaves behind.